# How to fix the display of elements using Swing in Java

Tags: java, swing, jframe, actionlistener

I'm working on an application using Swing in Java, however, I have a weird problem in the display, my code works perfectly fine, but the output is weird. When I run the program. The JFrame looks empty or something is missing (JMenuBar, JMenuItem, etc are invisible), then I maximize the screen, and all other stuff becomes visible, then I minimize the screen and it looks visible. I'm pretty sure that the code works fine, it's just a display problem. Can anyone help so that the first display looks fine?

Here is the code

```
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Menu");
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.setSize(400,200);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

    JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
    frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

    JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
    menubar.add(file);

    JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
    file.add(exit);


    JMenu help = new JMenu("Help");
    menubar.add(help);
    JMenuItem about = new JMenuItem("About");
    help.add(about);

    class exitaction implements ActionListener {

        public void actionPerformed (ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
    exit.addActionListener(new exitaction());

}
```

Comment: If you do not upload the code we can only guess. Try calling revalidate() after you have added your JMenuBar to your JFrame.

Comment: Please post your code.  And delete the images.  They don't help.

Comment: As mentioned, you should give us a [mcve]. And I don't think you should delete the images as they do help visualize the issue.

Comment: “I'm pretty sure that the code works fine”  —I’m not. Edit your question and show us your code.  At the very least, show us the code that creates the window, adds the menu bar, and shows the window.

Comment: Here is the entire code as suggested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the code below at the end. It'll work fine.

The method `setVisible` is an action, just like `show()` before JDK 1.5.

```
frame.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Thanks! it is working. So basically the set should be at the end to include JMenuBar and all other stuff added before.